# Should I attend a job interview with the intention of declining?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I have been offered an interview (I did not apply for) for an entry level position at Company B.

My current job has many benefits.  Free education, good salary, slightly shorter working hours and I haven't worked a weekend since I started 2 years ago.

Based on feedback of previous employees who used to work at Company B, the hours are longer (till midnight at times and sometimes weekends), they pay partially for education based on results, lower salary and it is very far from where I live.

Would it be rude of me to politely decline the interview based on the feedback of others?  Or is it better for me to attend, and if I decide I would rather stay, decline then? Would they be offended?.  Thank you

Comment: "Or is it better for me to attend, and if I decide I would rather stay, decline then" If there's even a small chance you may want the new job, now is when the cost is smallest to attend the interview and see how it goes.

Answer (score 7):

> Would it be rude of me to politely decline the interview based on the
>   feedback of others?

If you have already concluded that you definitely don't want the job, then it would make perfect sense to contact the company and decline the interview.

Most hiring managers would appreciate it that you don't want to waste their time.

On the other hand, if you aren't sure, you should attend the interview and make up your own mind about the company, rather than depending on the opinion of others.